# How to use JPQL for fetching DTO objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I've recently learned about dtos so In my application I've tried fetching DTOs using JPQL queries but I get Exception.

Here's my code:

```
public class Teacher {

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "teacher_phone_number",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")})
@Column(name = "phone_number")
private Set<String> phoneNumbers;

// getter setters
}


public class TeacherDTO {
private long id;

private String teacherName;

private Set<String> phoneNumber;

public TeacherDTO(long id, String teacherName, Set<String> phoneNumber) {
    this.id = id;
    this.teacherName = teacherName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

//Setter getters
}


public class TeacherRepositoryImpl {

@Override
public TeacherDTO fetchTeacherDTOById(Long id) {

    return entityManager.createQuery("select new service.dto.TeacherDTO(t.id, 
concat(t.firstName, ' ', t.lastName)" + ", tp.phoneNumbers) 
from Teacher t join t.phoneNumbers tp where 
    t.id = :id", TeacherDTO.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
}

}
```

Guys I wanted to add DTOs to my service layer so I had to use JPQL to fetch the dto entity. But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection 
element: phoneNumbers [select new service.dto.TeacherDTO(t.id, 
concat(t.firstName, ' ', t.lastName), tp.phoneNumbers) from 
model.Teacher t join t.phoneNumbers tp where t.id = :id]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Passing a collection like this is not possible out of the box as the JPA Constructor syntax does not support "aggregating", but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Teacher.class)
public interface TeacherDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getTeacherName();
    Set<String> getPhoneNumbers();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TeacherDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TeacherDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TeacherDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but it's best to fetch elements from the DB as entities and then convert them to DTOs later using something like Java's `ModelMapper`. See some examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application)